# Automake-1.14 is failing at make

Tags: linux, automake

I downloaded automake-1.14 by following this tutorial on Ubuntu 16.04
**./configure** passed without any error. But the moment I ran **make** it gave an error.

> I actually removed automake-1.15 from linux because when I was
>   installing protobuf 2.6.1 it says that i can't find automake-1.14. Therefore I remove automake by apt-get autoremove automake. And ran the following commands

```
$ wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.14.tar.gz
$ tar xvzf automake-1.14.tar.gz
$ cd automake-1.14
$ ./configure
$ make # FAIL HERE
$ sudo make install
```

The Error is the following:

```
anybody@anywhere:~/anyshare/automake-1.14$ make
  GEN      t/testsuite-part.am
  GEN      m4/amversion.m4
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && "/home/anybody/anyshare/automake-1.14/t/wrap/aclocal-1.14" 
Can't locate /home/anybody/anyshare/automake-1.14/bin/aclocal in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at /home/anybody/anyshare/automake-1.14/t/wrap/aclocal-1.14 line 29.
Makefile:2494: recipe for target 'aclocal.m4' failed
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 2
```

Comment: protobuf.  sorry typo

Comment: Supposing that `/home/anybody/anyshare/automake-1.14` is the directory you obtained by unpacking the Automake distribution, the file that the message complains about is (normally) generated by `configure`.  If in fact it is not present then go back and check `configure`'s output.  If it *is* present, then my best guess would be that your system's Perl doesn't like something about it.

Comment: Using that same tarball, the sequence generated by make for me (that is, the second column of the output) is `bin/automake,bin/aclocal,t/ax/shell-no-trail-bslash,t/ax/cc-no-c-o,runtest,doc/aclocal.1,doc/automake.1,lib/Automake/Config.pm,doc/aclocal-1.14.1,doc/automake-1.14.1,t/ax/test-defs.sh`.  I don't see m4/amversion.m4 at all.

Comment: Perhaps you ought to take a step back.  Since the objective is to build Protobuf (v2.6.1), and [the GitHub release tarball for that](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v2.6.1/protobuf-2.6.1.tar.gz) already packages Autoconf and Automake outputs, the version of Automake installed on the build machine, if any, should not be a factor.  Indeed, for me, `configure; make` worked straight out of the box and did not involve running either of those tools (and my installed version of Automake is 1.16.1).

Comment: ok @JohnBollinger ok  then something is not working from my part. I downloaded the Protobuf (v2.6.1) from the link u gave me and ran configure and make.  It gave me again warning: automake-1.14 is missing on your system

Comment: My best guess is that something about your filesystem or `tar` is producing an appearance that the Autotools-generated files are out of date, so the rule for rebuilding them is being triggered.  PB supports the `maintainer-mode` feature and enables it by default (which is great!), so try running `configure --disable-maintainer-mode; make`.  That should suppress any attempt to rebuild the build system.

Comment: Thank you @JohnBollinger it worked. But how did u find out that is so clever. if u want u can add it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the original problem -- and likely the problem building Automake -- was an incorrect appearance that the packages' Autotools-based build systems were out of date.

Generally speaking, Autotools-based packages should be distributed with the Autotools outputs pre-built, even though technically, they are derived files.  This avoids any need for the Autotools themselves to be installed on the build system for people who are just building the package on a supported system, not modifying or porting it.  Distribution packages built by an Autotools-based build system via `make dist` will in fact include them.

By default and typically, Autotools-based build systems include rules for rebuilding the build system itself if it is out of date.  This is a convenience for package maintainers.  Autoconf has a built-in mechanism to provide an option for disabling those rules (so-called "maintainer mode") at configuration time, though not all packages make use of it.

Normal operation of `tar` preserves file timestamps, but if your particular `tar` fails to do so, whether in general or in your particular case, or if your filesystem's timestamps have poor resolution, then unpacking the source tarballs may produce a result in which the Autotools outputs appear to be out of date.  In that case, unless suppressed, the rules for rebuilding the build system will be triggered when you run `make`.

If this happens to you, and the package's `configure` script supports the `maintainer-mode` option, then you can suppress the build-system rebuilding rules by including the `--disable-maintainer-mode` option when you `configure` the package.  Hindsight being 20/20, I can confidently state that this solves the Protobuf-building problem for you.